# Remove script tag from url YII 1.17

Tags: php, security, yii

I have a yii 1.17 application. Problem is any one can inject scripts in url. Ex: If user puts this after page url **?redir=%3C/SCript%3E%3CsvG/onLoad=prompt(7)%3E** application gives popup with given message.
How can i avoid this?

Main Layout:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <?php ?>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <md-content id="wrapper" layout-fill layout-margin layout-padding>
        <section class="grid_outer">
            <?php echo CHtml::encode($content); ?>
            <div class="md-grid-container md-grid-padding">
            </div>
        </section>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </md-content>
</body>
</html>
```

View File:

```
    <app-login></app-login>
```

Comment: Use `CHtml::encode()` when your rendering this `redir` value - that is general thing that you should do with everything that should not accept HTML, especial untrusted content form user.

Comment: @rob006 Tried with CHtml::encode() it prints angular directive which is there in my php view file instead of rendering. And also after adding CHtml::encode it still shows that popup.

Comment: You should share code that renders this value. But it looks like you added `CHtml::encode()` in a wrong place.

Comment: @rob006 updated in description.

Comment: If `$content` contains only `<app-login></app-login>`, then it is a bug in your Angular app, it is unrelated to Yii. In other case you should find exact place where this value is used, `<?php echo $content ?>` is too high on layout structure to be encoded, `$content` should already contain valid HTML and should not be encoded.